# How to refresh a column in a table

Tags: javascript, php

I have table in which only a column should refresh everytime.Table columns are as follows.

### EmployeeID    LoginTime     ShiftHours

Shift Hours has be refreshed every 10 seconds.

**JavaScript**

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
var eid = $('.refreshDiv').attr('id');
('#'+eid).load('liveload.php?empid='+eid);
}, 10000);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
$empid = $result[0];
    $login = $result[1];

?>
<tr ><td><?php echo $empid; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $result[1]; ?></td>
<td><div class ="refreshDiv" id="<?php echo $empid; ?>" ></div></td></tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

**liveload.php** is as follows

```
  <?php echo getShiftHours($_REQUEST['empid']); ?>
```

This works only for the first employee.  How can I refresh it for all the employees.  The javascript code should run for all the ids of the class refreshDiv and refresh their respective cells for the Shift Hours Column

Answer (score 0):

let try

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $.each($('.refreshDiv'), function() {
      ('#'+this.id).load('liveload.php?empid='+this.id);
   });

}, 10000);
```

Comment: in .each, pls alert(this.id) for testing

Comment: It alerts the first employee id every 10 seconds.  the error console shows this "TypeError: ("#" + this.id).load is not a function"

Comment: This problem is because of load function is not allow. pls make sure that you already used the latest version http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 0):

With a typical workaround, this is what that worked for me.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$.each($('.refreshDiv'), function() {   
var empid = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{eid:empid},
    url:"liveload.php",
    success: function(rs)
    {
     $('#'+empid).html(rs);
    }
});

});

}, 10000);
```

HTML & PHP

//while loop

```
<td ><div class ="refreshDiv" id="<?php echo $empid; ?>"></div></td>
```